# How can I properly follow all redirects on sites I am trying to scrape with cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, redirect, curl

I am using cURL to try to scrape an ASP site that is not on my server, with the following option to automatically follow redirects it comes across:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

but it is not properly following all redirects that the website sends back: it is putting several of the redirect URLs as relative to my server and my PHP script's path, instead of the website's server and the path that the website's pages should be relative to.  Is there any way to set the base path or server path in cURL, so my script can properly follow the relative redirects it comes across when scraping through the other website?

For example:  If I authenticate on their site and then try to access "https://www.theirserver.com/theirapp/mainForm/securepage.aspx" with my script at "https://www.myserver.com/php/myscript.php", then, under some circumstances, their website tries to redirect back to their login page, but this causes a big problem, because the redirect sends my cURL client to "https://www.myserver.com/php/mainForm/login.aspx", that is, '/mainForm/login.aspx' relative to my script on my server, instead of the correct "https://www.theirserver.com/theirapp/mainForm/login.aspx" relative to the site I am scraping on their server.

I would expect cURL's `FOLLOWLOCATION` option to properly follow relative redirects based on the "Location:" header of the web pages I am accessing, but it seems that it doesn't and can't.  Since this seems to not work, preferably I want a way to tell cURL a base path for the server or for all relative redirects it sees, so I can just use `FOLLOWLOCATION`. If not, then I need to figure out some code that will do the same thing `FOLLOWLOCATION` does, but that can let me specify a base path to handle these relative URLs when it comes across them.

I see several similar questions about following relative paths with cURL, but none of the answers have any good suggestions for dealing with this problem, where I don't own the website's server and I don't know every single redirect that might come up.  In fact, none of the answers I've seen for similar questions seem to even understand that a person might be trying to scrape an external website and would want any relative redirects they come across while scraping the site to just be relative to that site.

EDIT:  Here is the code in question:

```
$urlLogin = "https://www.theirsite.com/theirApp/MainForm/login.aspx"
$urlSecuredPage = "https://www.theirsite.com/theirApp/ContentPages/content.aspx"
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0;   Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; yie8)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

// GET login page
$data=curl_exec($ch);

// Read ASP viewstate and eventvalidation fields
$viewstate = parseExtract($data,$regexViewstate, 1);
$eventval = parseExtract($data, $regexEventVal, 1);

//set POST data
$postData = '__EVENTTARGET='.$eventtarget
      .'&__EVENTARGUMENT='.$eventargument
      .'&__VIEWSTATE='.$viewstate
      .'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.$eventval
      .'&'.$nameUsername.'='.$valUsername
      .'&'.$namePassword.'='.$valPassword
      .'&'.$nameLoginBtn.'='.$valLoginBtn;

// POST authentication
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);     
$data = curl_exec($ch);

/****************************************************************** 
 GET secure page  (This is where a redirect fails... when getting
 the secure page, it redirects to /mainForm/login.aspx relative to my 
 script, instead of /mainForm/login.aspx on their site.
*****************************************************************/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlSecuredPage);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);     
$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $data;  // Page Not Found
```

Comment: I don't understand how cURL is exhibiting the behaviour you describe. If you access a URL on `https://www.theirserver.com` and it redirects using domain-relative addresses, it should not be possible for it to follow your own domain, since cURL is not aware of this information. The only way this could happen is if cURL was issuing `Location` headers as script output, and your web-based script was following them - but cURL does not operate that way. I wonder whether we need to see some code (something that is worth adding as a matter of course, incidentally).

Comment: Presumably the remote server is using HTTP/1.1? If so, that supports domain-relative addresses, and cURL should be fine with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be running into redirects that are JavaScript redirects.

To find out what is there:

This will give you additional info.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
```

You should set fail on error:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
```

You may also need to see all the Request and Response headers:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

The big thing you are missing is  `curl_getinfo($ch);`
It has info on all the redirects and the headers.

You may want to turn off: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

And do each request individually.  You can get the redirect location from `curl_getinfo("redirect_url")`

Or you can set CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS to the number of successful redirects, then do a separate curl request for the problem redirect location

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

When you get the response, if no curl error, get the resposne header

```
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch)){
      $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
      echo $data;
  }
  else {
    $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
    $responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
    $data= substr($data,$skip);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $info = var_export($info,true);
   }
   echo $responseHeader . $info . $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to web scraping a webpage is to use 2 PHP Packages = Guzzle + DomCrawler.

I made a lot of tests with this combination and i came to the conclusion that this is the best choice.

[Here](http://www.ymc.ch/en/webscraping-in-php-with-guzzle-http-and-symfony-domcrawler), you will find an example for your implementation.

Let me know if you have any problem! ;)